# How do i get a vertical menu to slide out with my jquery mobile panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

So i have a menu(only icons) that is on the right side of my screen and I am wanting to get the icons to slide out with my panel when the panel opens.  but i want the menu to be visible when the panel is closed.  One image will open one panel and another image will open another panel.

```
<div class="buttons right">
            <a href="#rightpanel3" data-role="button" data-inline="true" class="filter">One</a> 
            <a href="#rightpanel1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" class="layers">Two</a> 
            <a href="#rightpanel2" data-role="button" data-inline="true" class="list">Three</a> 
            <a href="#rightpanel4" data-role="button" data-inline="true" class="settings">four</a>
</div>
<div data-role="panel" id="rightpanel3" data-position="right"
            data-display="overlay" data-dismissible="false" data-theme="b">
            <h3>Search/Filter</h3>
            <h4 class="top heading">Search</h4>
            <h4 class="heading">Filter</h4>
</div>
```

jsfiddle:  [jsfiddle.net/5GhPM](http://jsfiddle.net/5GhPM)

Comment: ok i added my code.  Right now i have the buttons in the first div and those when clicked call out to the panels.  Which works and opens up the panel but my buttons are hidden behind the panel and i want them to slide out with the panel.

Comment: Share all of the relevant code, incluiding the jQuery/Javascript, and if possible, share a jsFiddle.

Comment: Here is a quick jsFiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/5GhPM/

Answer (score 1):

May need some tweaking, but this works:

```
$("#rightpanel3").on("panelopen", function() {
    $(".buttons.right").animate({ marginRight: $("#rightpanel3").width() });
});

$("#rightpanel3").on("panelclose", function() {
    $(".buttons.right").animate({ marginRight: -($("#rightpanel3").width()) });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yRu4q/

The events are documented [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/).